# Temporary disable fontawesome JS

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

Is it possible to temporary disable fontawesome so it doesn't try to render icons until I activate it again?

It couldn't find anything in the docs. I'm using the JavaScript version.

Fontawesome is included like below and should stop doing its thing for a while until I tell it to start looking for `<i>` tags again.

```
<head>
  <script defer src="/your-path-to-fontawesome/js/all.js"></script> <!--load all styles -->
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <!-- uses solid style -->
  <i class="far fa-user"></i> <!-- uses regular style -->
  <i class="fal fa-user"></i> <!-- uses light style -->
  <!--brand icon-->
  <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i> <!-- uses brands style -->
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: sure, I added some code